# Minimal polynomial with $f(\alpha)=0$

Tags: extension-field

I'm learning this stuff for the first time so please bear with me.
I'm given $\alpha=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}i$ and asked to find the minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ which has $\alpha$ as a root.
I'm ok with this part, quite sure I can find such a polynomial like so:

$\alpha = \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}i$

$\iff \alpha - \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{2}i$

squaring both sides,

$\iff \alpha^2 -2\sqrt{3}\alpha + 3 = -2$

$\iff \alpha^2+5 = 2\sqrt{3}\alpha$

again squaring both sides,

$\iff \alpha^4+10\alpha^2+25 = 12\alpha^2$

$\iff \alpha^4-2\alpha^2+25 = 0$

Therefore $f(x)=x^4-2x^2+25$ should have $f(\alpha)=0$.

My question is how can I be sure this polynomial is minimal, i.e., can I be sure there isn't some lower degree polynomial out there with $\alpha$ as a root?

Comment: Any polynomial with $\alpha$ as a root must have the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ as a factor.

Comment: I'm still not sure how I can verify that the polynomial I found is of minimal degree, or how to go about deciding such for examples like this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. Writing them in the basis $1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}i,\sqrt{6}i$ of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}i]$ we get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ \alpha \\ \alpha^2 \\ \alpha^3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & -3 & 7 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ \sqrt{3} \\ \sqrt{2}i \\ \sqrt{6}i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The key point is that the matrix is invertible.
You can prove this by row reduction or by computing its determinant and checking that it is not zero.

Answer (score 4):

We see that the four roots of $f$ are $\pm\sqrt3\pm\sqrt2i$ (where the $\pm$ are independent). You can show this for instance by inserting and calculating, or by noting that your method to find $f$ gives the same polynomial for all four numbers.

Any field extension of $\Bbb Q$ with $\alpha$ in it will also contain $\alpha^3=-3\sqrt3+7\sqrt2i$, and thus both $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt2i$ (technically you can stop here, because this already shows that $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]\geq 4]$). Therefore such a field also contains the three other roots of $f$. Which is to say, any polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ that has $\alpha$ as a root also has all the other three roots of $f$ as roots. So your $f$ is minimal.